# SSL certificate Issue when trying to acces Parse via PHP

Tags: php, ssl, parse-platform, openssl

Before I start please note the following: This question ist not about parsing like e.g. json objects. It's about the [Parse](http://www.parse.com) backend.

I've been trying to access my Parse backend via PHP. The Installation of the Parse SDK is done and this Part works as far as I can tell.
But when I try to access my Parse backend, I recieve the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. 
Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' in C:\xampp\htdocs\parsetest\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php:264 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsetest\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(927): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', '/1/classes/Test...', NULL, '{"foo":"bar"}', false) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsetest\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseObject.php(838): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseObject), false) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\parsetest\index.php(15): Parse\ParseObject->save() 
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\parsetest\vendor\parse\php-sdk\src\Parse\ParseClient.php on line 264
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this error? Here are some further informations:

My development environment:
- Win10
- XAMPP (with PHP 5.6)

What I've already done:
- Installed composer
- Installed Parse SDK (With the Parse PHP getting started Tutorial)
- Installed an self generated OpenSSL certificate like according to this [tutorial](https://latunyj.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/generating-self-signed-certificate-in-xampp-win32-for-apache-web-server/)

Currently my PHP file for testing the Parse connection looks like this:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;

ParseClient::initialize('some', 'Parse', 'information');

use Parse\ParseObject;

$testObject = ParseObject::create("TestObject");
$testObject->set("foo", "bar");

$testObject->save();
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS and SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed, CA is OK](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6400300) and [Enabling SSL Support for CURL in XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4396075). Where did you get your SSL/TLS server certificate?

Comment: Thx for your answer. It works know. The .pem i created was not recognized by the php.ini. Now its fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the mistake. The .pem i created was not recognized by the php.ini. Now its fine ;)